# TypeScript - null versus undefined

Tags: typescript

The [TypeScript Coding Guidelines](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines) state

> Use **undefined**. Do not use null

Having just read another [article on ECMAScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606306/es5-when-to-use-null-and-when-to-use-undefined), which advocates for null over undefined, I was wondering whether Microsoft’s or the TypeScript team’s rationale is known for this decision?

Comment: As stated in the guidelines, it is chosen for team consistency for that project, it is not meant as prescriptive guideline for typescript community to follow. So that's their rationale, 'consistency'.

Comment: @RosdiKasim consistency is all well and good, however I was wondering if there was any technical rationale? The other article (now in the post) seems to have more of a technical stance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No rationale is necessary for guidelines, the requirement could be chosen at random in order to keep the code base consistent.

As for this guideline, `undefined` takes more characters to type but doesn't need to be explicitly assigned to nullable variable or property:

```
class Foo {
  bar: number|undefined;
}

function foo(bar: number|undefined) {}
```

vs.

```
class Foo {
  bar: number|null = null;
}

function foo(bar: number|null = null) {}
```

Also, it's less convenient to check the type of `null` value at runtime because `typeof val === 'object'` for both `null` and object value, while it's `typeof val === 'undefined'` for `undefined`.

There is relevant TSLint rule that addresses this concern, [`no-null-keyword`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-null-keyword/).

Comment: That's the best answer. I would like to add that, in early versions of JavaScript, an argument against `undefined` was that it [could be reassigned](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/undefined#Description) as a global variable. But in 2018, there is no downside to `undefined`.

Comment: @Paleo That's true. This would cause TS compilation error any way.

Comment: But `val === null` is easier than `typeof val === 'undefined'`. And you may also use `val == null` if you like. So I don't think convenient of type checking is a reason.

Comment: @tsh It could be `val == null` or `val === undefined` for undefined as well. I meant cases where `typeof` checks are needed (e.g. `val` is potentially not defined) and an object is expected. That `typeof val === 'object'` for `null` results in ambiguity and requires additional check.

Answer (score 5):

I made some research few months ago and I came out with the fact that undefined must be prioritize using tslint rule 'no-null-keyword'.

I tried to change my codebase and I had some issues.
Why? 
Because I'm using an API that return null for empty fields.

I struggled because of the tslint triple-equals rule.

`if (returnedData === undefined) // will be false because returnedData is null`

Which let you 2 options:

1) Add some parameters to your triple-equals rules.

"triple-equals": [true, "allow-null-check"] and do `If (returnedData == null)`

allow-null-check allow "==" for null

2) Use `If (returnedData)` instead but it checks if null/undefined/empty string or a zero

Comment: _"but it checks if `null` OR `undefined`"_ ... or an empty string or a zero. But a test `if (returnedData)` remains a good test if you are sure that the value is an object or null/undefined, never a scalar value.

Comment: @Paleo indeed, that's why I go first option, i'll add

Comment: I think the first option (with `== null`) will have the same result: `0`, `""`, `false`, `null` and `undefined` are all `==`. The operator `==` is just a bad practice. The second option is better.

Comment: @Paleo https://gyazo.com/a90c339be646f49170bafd58cdc625df first option is taking undefined or null second is taking all

Comment: I didn't know. Thank you.

Comment: Do not  change the existing  codebase, but suppress the rule, that not fit to existing code. Just follow lint recommendation in a new code.

Answer (score 2):

Why use null over undefined?

In javascripts objects are dynamic without any type information. therefor:

```
var person
person.namme
```

could either be a misspell or it could be the `name` property. If you use undefined as null you won't know when debugging if:

- variable/property is not initialized yet, or
- you miss typed the property name.

Therefor null is preferable over undefined, you defer between:

- forgot to initialize property and
- wrong property used.

That said: Typescript is typed. thus the following code:

```
var person
person.namme
```

would result in a type error at compilation. Thus null in that sense is no longer needed.

That said, i still prefer null over undefined.

Answer (score 0):

From https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-null-keyword/

> Rationale
>
> Instead of having the dual concepts of null andundefined in a
> codebase, this rule ensures that only undefined is used.
>
> JavaScript originally intended undefined to refer to a value that
> doesn’t yet exist, while null was meant to refer to a value that does
> exist but points to nothing. That’s confusing. undefined is the
> default value when object members don’t exist, and is the return value
> for newer native collection APIs such as Map.get when collection
> values don’t exist.
>
> To remove confusion over the two similar values, it’s better to stick
> with just undefined.