# vue-class-component : how to create and initialize reflective data

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-class-components

I'm using vuejs with typescript and vue-class-component. I'm trying to create a custom component with reactive data.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input v-model="data.name" placeholder="Name">
        <input v-model="data.value" placeholder="Value">
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

interface Model {
    name: string;
    value: number;
}
@Component
export default class ClubVue extends Vue {
    private data: Model;

    public mounted() {
        this.data = {...this.$store.getters.data};
    }
}
</script>
```

In this first version, I've got this error :

> Property or method "data" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render

That's normal, as said in vue-class-component page, undefined data won't be reflective. I need to initialize data to null. Furthermore, i get this typescript error:

> Property 'data' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in
>   the constructor

So I want to do this:

```
private data: Model = null;
```

But I get this typescript error:

> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Model'.

I don't wan't to change the data type to `Model | null` because I would have to check if data is null everywhere I will use it, and I know that data will never be null.

```
private data!: Model;
```

Does not work either because data will be undefined and so won't be reactive.

I don't want to turn off typescript checks because they are useful for other parts of code.

Is there a proper way to initialize data here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A correct type for such property is:

```
private data: Model | null = null;
```

It can be used with type guards:

```
if (this.data) {
  console.log(this.data.name); // Model
}
```

Or non-null assertion operator:

```
console.log(this.data!.name); // Model
```

A workaround is to cheat typing system with assertion:

```
private data: Model = null as unknown as Model;
```

vue-class-component doesn't take TypeScript into account because [`undefined` is easier to handle in TypeScript than `null`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746803/typescript-null-versus-undefined), particularly because this would allow to mark a property as optional.

> I know that data will never be null.

It will be `null` until the component is mounted, this leaves a room for mistake:

```
public created() {
    console.log(this.data.name); // runtime error but no compilation error
}

public mounted() {
    this.data = {...this.$store.getters.data};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a getter instead of assigning the data directly, assuming the data is set in the store when it is created. Make sure your store getters are typesafe!

```
@Component
export default class ClubVue extends Vue {
    private _data: Model | undefined;

    get data(): Model {
        if (!this._data) {
            this._data = {...this.$store.getters.data};
        }
        return this._data;
    }
}
```

This way, `data` will never be undefined, since it will either return `_data` or set `_data` to the current store content and then return that.
This may fail if `_data` is a primitive instead of an object, and evaluates to `false` (e.g. (Number)`0` or (String)`""`). In that case, use `this._data === undefined` instead of `!this._data`.

You can also shorten the getter to

```
get data():Model {
    return this._data = this._data || {...this.$store.getters.data};
}
```

but this is less clear, especially if the reader is not aware that an assignment will return the value/reference that is being assigned, and even worse to read with primitive types:

```
return this._data = 
    this._data === undefined 
        ? {...this.$store.getters.data} 
        : this._data;
```

Comment: I support this approach, yet `typeof(this._data) === 'undefined'` is redundant, `this._data === undefined` is more readable but unnecessary too because it can be either undefined or an object in this snippet. As for `private _data: Model | undefined`, it can be shortened to `private _data?: Model`.

Comment: Yep, in this snippet the `typeof` is unneccessary, I mentioned it to make sure that readers are aware of primitive types when this is adapted to fit other code. I agree on the shortening of the undefined check and will edit the post to fit it.  
Although I will leave the `_data` declaration as I wrote it, mainly because it makes it clearer that it will be `undefined` initially. While I usually use the optional parameter in my code, I prefer longer, more explicit forms that make it easier to grasp when writing code on this platform - makes it easier for beginners to understand.
Thank you!