# Really check if undefined with typeof

Tags: javascript, typeof

What is the better solution?

```
if(typeof bla === "undefined" || bla === null)...
```

Or

```
if(bla)...
```

If I do the second solution, do I really need to check whether its undefined?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer is "it depends on what exactly you are trying to do".

Comment: "Really check if undefined"... do you mean that, or do you mean "undefined or null", since you are checking for null too in those examples.

Comment: A property, when it has no definition, is undefined. Put that way, it's pretty obvious.
null is an object. It's type is null. undefined is not an object, it's type is undefined. That part is less obvious.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429225/javascript-null-or-undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on what you expect the variable to contain.

If it should for example contain an object, the second option works fine because any object reference is truthy.

If it should for example contain a boolean value, the second option won't work at all, because `false` would give the same result as a non-existing value.

Comment: So to be sure, check for undefined and null is the better solution?

Comment: @Christian: That depends on what you need to be sure of. There is no ideal method that works for all situations. A `null` value can for example be a perfectly valid value in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

> > do I really need to check whether its undefined?

No, both undefined and null resolve to false. Second option is definitely better.

Answer (score 0):

To *"check if undefined"*, the best solution is usually a third one :

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/VqaTX/)

```
function isDef(obj) {
    var undefined;
    return obj === undefined;
}
```

This checks if the object is undefined without losing time with `typeof` and this test doesn't validate as true with `""`, `null`, `NaN` or `0` as would your second test.

The only pitfall is that someone can override the global `undefined` object. Not possible in ES5 strict mode, but your code should shield from this. Shadowing `undefined` with a local `var undefined;` definition does that for you.

Also, by using an `isDef` function you allow for better, portable minification and simpler logic.

```
if (isDef(x)) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
};
```

Comment: what does the line `var undefined;` add?

Comment: @smerny In my opinion this line is a useless protection. As undefined can't be redefined in the global scope, it's simpler and smarter to just check obj===undefined.