# Javascript null or empty string does not work

Tags: javascript, null

I am trying to test that my string is null or empty, however it does not work.

My Code :

```
var veri = {
  YeniMusteriEkleTextBox: $('#MyTextbox').val(),
};

if (veri.YeniMusteriEkleTextBox === "" || 
    veri.YeniMusteriEkleTextBox == '' || 
    veri.YeniMusteriEkleTextBox.length == 0 || 
    veri.YeniMusteriEkleTextBox == null) {
  alert("Customer Name can not be empty!!!");
}
```

How can ı check YeniMusteriEkleTextBox is null or empty ?

Comment: Where is this code located? Inside of a `document ready` handler?

Comment: Notice that `'' === ""` and that checking for `.length == 0` was equivalent when you did knew that it was a string

Answer (score 4):

I would use the ! operator to test if it is empty, undefined etc.

```
if (!veri.YeniMusteriEkleTextBox) {
    alert("Customer Name can not be empty!!!");
}
```

Also you do not need the comma after `YeniMusteriEkleTextBox: $('#MyTextbox').val(),`

Also testing for a length on an object that may be undefined will throw an error as the length will not be 0, it will instead be undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [`.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the value to remove leading and trailing white space:

```
var veri = {
    YeniMusteriEkleTextBox: $('#YeniMusteriAdiTextbox_I').val().trim()
};
```

The `.trim` method doesn't exist on some older browsers, there's a shim to add it at the above MDN link.

You can then just test `!veri.YeniMusteriEkleTextBox` or alternatively `veri.YeniMusteriEkleTextBox.length  === 0`:

```
if (!veri.YeniMusteriEkleTextBox) {
    alert("Customer Name can not be empty!!!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
if (!veri.YeniMusteriEkleTextBox) {
```

This also checks for `undefined` which [is not the same as null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429225/javascript-null-or-undefined)

Comment: Additionally OP, if `YeniMusteriEkleTextBox` was `null`, your code would have a runtime exception as `null` does not have the property `length`.  When using `null`/`undefined` checks, make sure those occur first as they are (1) the fastest and (2) minimize risk of runtime exceptions as we see here.

Answer (score -1):

Since no one else is suggestion $.trim, I will

Note I removed the trailing comma too and use the ! not operator which will work for undefined, empty null and also 0, which is not a valid customer name anyway

```
var veri = {
  YeniMusteriEkleTextBox: $.trim($('#MyTextbox').val())
};

if (!veri.YeniMusteriEkleTextBox) {
  alert("Customer Name can not be empty!!!");
}
```