# Is it better to return `undefined` or `null` from a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, function, null, return, undefined

I have a function which I have written which basically looks like this:

```
function getNextCard(searchTerms) {
  // Setup Some Variables

  // Do a bunch of logic to pick the next card based on termed passed through what I'll call here as 'searchTerms' all of this logic is omitted because it's not important for my question.
  // ...

  // If we find a next card to give, than give it
  if (nextCardFound)
    return nextCardFound;

  // Otherwise - I'm returning undefined
  return undefined;
}
```

**Question: Would it be better to return "null" here?**

I can pass whatever I want back - obviously...  I just wasn't sure what is the best thing to use.

The code that calls this function knows how to deal with undefined (it actually won't ever really happen unless something goes horribly wrong)

The reason I'm asking this question is that I heard somewhere something that sounded like "Don't assign undefined to variables" or something - that it will make it harder to debug.  So, the fact that I can see that `null` gets passed back tells me that the return is working - but basically function similar to `undefined`.

---

### Documentation:

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) Didn't answer my question... google didn't either :\

[This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604749/what-reason-is-there-to-use-null-instead-of-undefined-in-javascript) - was way too broad for what I'm trying to figure out here.

Comment: doesn't this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/why-is-null-an-object-and-whats-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined) answer?

Comment: In my opinion, return `null`. Leave `undefined` to JavaScript itself. However, there is no "better" so this is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @warkentien2 Thanks, this was helpful - but I'm still unclear as to what the convention is here for returning from a getter function.

Comment: I read `null` as "there is no appropriate value for what you're asking for" and `undefined` as "I can't work out what you're asking for".

Comment: @warkentien2 that question, and the one I linked in my answer, are related, but both seem to be asking *what* is the difference between them and not *when* to use one or the other as a return value.

Comment: You could alternatively return `false`, or "search term not found", to notify caller of function which performs search for `searchTerm` that a search did occur, though no matches were found.

Comment: The question is incorrectly closed as opinion-based. There are good reasons explaining why undefined is preferred. See https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-null-keyword/

Comment: See also TS question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746803/typescript-null-versus-undefined/77038126#77038126

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I will argue there is no best way, and even standard functions sometimes choose one or the other.

For example:

- [[Prototype]]

  Ordinary objects have a [[Prototype]] internal slot, which determines from which other object they inherit from. Of course, there must be a way to say that an object does not inherit from any other one. In this case, "there is no such object" is represented using `null`.
- `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`

  It is expected to return a property descriptor, that is, an object which describes a property (e.g. value, writability, enumerability and configurability). However, the property may not exist. In this case, "there is no such property" is represented using `undefined`.
- `document.getElementById`

  It is expected to return the element with the given ID. However, there might be no element with that ID. In this case, "there is no such element" is represented using `null`.

So just choose whatever you prefer or think makes more sense for your specific case.

Comment: after [reading this](http://ryanmorr.com/exploring-the-eternal-abyss-of-null-and-undefined/) I decided to suggest the `void 0` technique for future viewers of this answer.  I also added some code to try and make your point more clear.  Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Great point here - another perfect example is [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Answer (score 173):

Undefined typically refers to something which has not yet been assigned a value (yet). Null refers to something which definitively has no value. In that case, I would recommend returning a null. Note that a function with no specified return value implicitly returns undefined.

From the ECMAScript2015 spec

> **4.3.10 undefined value**
>
> primitive value used when a variable has not been assigned a value
>
> **4.3.12 null value**
>
> primitive value that represents the 
>   intentional absence of any object value

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-undefined-type

Further reading:

[When is null or undefined used in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429225/javascript-null-or-undefined)

Comment: Yes, undefined is the value used when a variable has not been assigned a value. Why exactly does that imply you shouldn't return undefined in a function?

Comment: @Oriol, in my mind, since a void function returns undefined, that is a reserved value for functions of that type, so that when handling the return value of a function, null tells me it decided to return null, whereas undefined tells me it either decided to return undefined, or it decided not to return anything, but I don't definitively know which. Further, if I am doing `var x=someFunc();`, I am intentionally assigning x a value, and would rather it not pass any tests which indicate it has not (or may have not) been assigned a value. Just imho

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is how it was intended to be used in the spec

Comment: `null` refers to the absence of any `object` value. As much as I like to use it because it's the same word from other languages, a number or a string should be undefined, not null, according to the spec (also that's why `typeof null === 'object'`)

Comment: @SergioRosas can you link to the spec that says that undefined should be used for a number or a string?

Comment: I'm not saying `undefined` should only be used for string number and non objects, or that you can't use it to say absence of `object` value, but just from those specs `null` seems to be reserved for absence of `object` value. In the end, how you use `undefined` or `null` depends on your code and how you define your interfaces

Comment: I don't read it that way. I read it as: If you define a variable but don't initialize it, it will instead have an initial value of undefined. Null should be used by the programmer to intentionally indicate that a variable is empty. IMHO undefined should never be assigned to a variable by the programmer, leave it up to the js engine to use it. The term "object" value is misleading, since in JS even the primitives behave like objects for the most part due to autoboxing

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. To be fair, I don't mind using one over the other (although I'm more used to `null`) as long as you stick with one, but having 2 values to indicate absence of value (whatever the "type") is always confusing

Answer (score 85):

I will give you my personal opinionated way of choosing between the two.

My simple question is: **could the value, given another input/state/context be defined to something?**

If the answer is yes then use `null` else use `undefined`. More generally any function returning an object should return `null` when the intended object does not exist. Because it could exist given another input/state/context.

`null` represents the **absence of value** for a given input/state/context. It implicitly means that the *concept* of the value itself exist in the context of your application but may be absent.
In your example the concept of a next card exists but the card itself may not exist. `null` should be used.

`undefined` implicitly represents the **absence of meaning** of that value in your application's context. For example, if I manipulate a `user` object with a given set of properties and I try to access the property `pikatchu`. The value of this property should be set to `undefined` because in my context it doesn't make any sense to have such a property.

Comment: This rings so true to me. IMO pure functions should return `null`, while functions with side-effects should return `undefined`, when thinking like a functional programmer.

Comment: Aren't the default JS functions conflicting with this? When I use the find function, for example, it returns undefined when no value was found. But it could have returned something when I inputted something else, right?

Answer (score 5):

I would argue that in this case, `null` should be returned.

If you consider the question from a theoretical computer science point of view then *undefined* is used to indicate **non-termination**/ **non-computability** (i.e. the placeholder for an undefined point `x` of a [partial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function) `f` which is often written `f(x) = ⊥`).

`getNextCard` however seems to be able to compute the next card (if it exists) and also be able to compute if there is no next card. In other words, the function is [total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function#Total_function) since it terminates for every input.

That being said, a **special value** signalling termination without meaningful result (i.e. "there's no card I can return for this input") is required and this for me is `null` not `undefined`.

---

**NOTES:**

You can see some support for this argument in some other typed languages as well where termination without meaningful result are expressed using an [option type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) (sometimes also referred to as *nullable type*). An example for this is is *Maybe* in *Haskell*.

On the other hand, we of course do not know what `undefined` in JavaScript is really supposed to mean. So, the analogy to *undefined* is a bit tenous. Moreover, since we always want to work with total functions, this amounts to saying "never return `undefined` from a function". Which seems to be a bit strict, since it would limit the use of `undefined` to properties/ variables which have not been set.

In the end, my personal preference is never to return `undefined` where I can return `null` and I would also argue that this is the better coding convention (because among other things `x !== null` is shorter than `typeof x !== 'undefined'`).

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what u need to do with the returned value.

typeof null returns an object. that object has a value of undefined

typeof undefined returns undefined

Comment: Personally i usually use null.

Comment: *"that object has a value of undefined"* No it's not and it's not an object, it's Null. `typeof` doesn't necessarily return the true data type of a value, it has a map that maps data types to labels and returns the corresponding label.

Comment: Don't trust `typeof`, despite its name it doesn't tell the type of a value.

Answer (score 4):

`undefined` is not something you should assign to. You might want to consider to return something else other than `undefined`. In your case, even if you don't return anything at all, the result will be `undefined` already. So, I'd suggest to go with `null` instead.

Consider this sample,

```
function getSomething() {
     // .. do something
     return undefined;
}

function doSomething() {
     // .. I'm not gonna return anything.
}

var a = getSomething();
var b = doSomething();
```

Above sample result in `a === b`, which is `undefined`. The difference is that you save 1 statement execution.

Comment: @Oriol I mean, `undefined` does not have to be assigned. All declared variable without values are already `undefined`.

Comment: @choz & @Oriol - as mentioned before by @chiliNUT "Note that a function with no specified return value implicitly returns undefined." - this is true because `(function(){ /* code */ })()` returns null in a console.

Comment: @JeremyIglehart That code actually does not return anything. And else, it gives `undefined` on my chrome and firefox console.

Comment: OK I didn't understand your point. Yes, if you don't return anything explicitly, undefined will be returned implicitly. But why does that matter?

Comment: @Oriol, I think what @choz was trying to say (as a few other also mentioned on this question) that if I want to return `undefined` if something else doesn't return earlier - I don't need to because the function's default behavior if you don't return anything is to return undefined - they are just saying that this is not needed.  Further... I like what you had to say about built-in getter functions returning null.  Please post your answer to that effect and I will accept it.

Comment: I still prefer to explicitly return `undefined` as it documents the intent of the code. Otherwise, when I see a function that doesn't return anything I have to ask myself if the dev who wrote it, just forgot to return something.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example where `undefined` makes more sense than `null`:

I use a wrapper function for `JSON.parse` that converts its exception to `undefined`:

```
// parses s as JSON if possible and returns undefined otherwise
// return undefined iff s is not a string or not parseable as JSON; undefined is not a valid JSON value https://stackoverflow.com/a/14946821/524504
function JSON_parse_or_undefined(s) {
    if ("string" !== typeof s) return undefined

    try {
        const p = JSON.parse(s)
        return p
    } catch (x){}

    return undefined
}
```

Note that `null` is valid in JSON while `undefined` is not.

Comment: I see what you're doing there - and I can't say you're wrong - because in a sense I think you could do this here and it would be fine.  I have a different pattern that I use to do this operation that I like better because I do a "validation" step after.  I feel like this is getting validation mixed with returning the value.  Here is what I do: `let getStringOrJSON = value => {
  try {
    value = JSON.parse(value);
  }
  catch(e) {
    return value;
  }
  return value;
};`.  Now, I'm sure the two returns could be handled differently, and might not win the JS golf competition. It works.

Answer (score 1):

First answer is right. They have theoretically different meaning. However it's not always clear which to pick up.

I tend to use null in my development although I think that's completely subjective thing.

I use that mostly because:

1. undefined variable might be overwritten in old browsers so returning it is a little bit more complicated. This same issue forces you to use `typeof var === 'undefined'` when getting function results. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript)
2. Other languages tend to use null widely, a lot of them don't even have undefined (php for example). That gives me kind of consistency when quickly swapping between languages.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is very debatable what to use. I prefer code that is semantically as accurate as possible, so I think `undefined` is appropriate in this case.

I think of `null` assignments as meaning "a variable set to nothing". This is as opposed to `undefined` meaning "this thing isn't there at all"

As a previous answer pointed out, returning `undefined` has issues, and it's completely up to you whether that bothers you. It wouldn't bother me.

Comment: But `document.getElementById('iDoNotExist')` returns `null`, even though the meaning is closer to "this thing isn't there at all". If standard methods do it, why not OP?

Comment: @Oriol I actually like your reasoning the most.  Please post an answer to this effect and I will accept it.  ( I might even add a few edits if needed )

Comment: Yah @Oriol, this is why I actually enjoy debates, even on Q/A sites. It's really good to get counter examples. And you've provided a good one.

Comment: On the other hand, `array.find()` returns `undefined` if the array doesn't contain searched value. It's not consistent, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

All answers are correct. I'm adding my 2 cents.

Another important question to ask is:

> **What will the caller of your function do?**

In most cases it wouldn't matter anyway. Js/Ts developers usually check something as `!fnCall()` instead of `fnCall() === undefined`.

But in some cases, `!` doesn't do what we want. Like if the function returns `int`, someone might be tempted to do a `fnCall() === undefined` check since `0` is a valid response.