# how to disable event in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to disable event in jquery ?

ined to disable the cell after click on it
i tried with $('.cells').off();
after event.target 
but it doesn't work
and also i tried with $('.cells').unbind();
after event.target 
and after click listener but i have the same bugs

```
    const changeTurn = function Turne() {
        let board, result;
        let player1 = '';
        let player2 = '';
        if (turn === 1) {
            if (player1 !== '' || winningCase(gameBoard()) !== 0 ||player2 !== '') {
               return;
            }
            player1 = 'X'
             event.target.innerHTML = player1
            board = gameBoard();
            result = winningCase(board);
            if (result !== 0) {
                gameOver(result);
                return;
            }
            turn++
            moveCuont++
} else {

            if (player1 !== '' || winningCase(gameBoard()) !== 0 ||
                player2 !== '') {
                return;
            }
            player2 = 'O'
            event.target.innerHTML = player2
            board = gameBoard();
            result = winningCase(board);
            if (result !== 0) {
                gameOver(result);
                return;
            }
           turn--
           moveCuont++
            eve.off('click')
        }
        result = checkWinner(board);
        if (moveCuont === 9) {
            gameOver(result);
            return;
        }
    }
    $(".cells").click(changeTurn)
```

Comment: You can use [off](https://api.jquery.com/off/) to turn the event listener off. Syntax would look like `$(".cells").off('click', changeTurn);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As was mentioned, you have to define the event name that you want to turn off with you use `.off()`. In your script, you do not define `event` nor `eve`, so the `event.target` and `eve.off()` would both fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise the following code.

```
function changeTurn(event) {
  var board, result;
  var player1 = '';
  var player2 = '';
  var self = $(event.target);
  if (turn === 1) {
    if (player1 !== '' || winningCase(gameBoard()) !== 0 ||player2 !== '') {
      return false;
    }
    player1 = 'X'
    self.html(player1);
    board = gameBoard();
    result = winningCase(board);
    if (result !== 0) {
      gameOver(result);
      return false;
    }
    turn++;
    moveCuont++;
  } else {
    if (player1 !== '' || winningCase(gameBoard()) !== 0 ||
      player2 !== '') {
      return false;
    }
    player2 = 'O'
    self.html(player2);
    board = gameBoard();
    result = winningCase(board);
    if (result !== 0) {
      gameOver(result);
      return false;
    }
    turn--;
    moveCuont++;
    self.off('click');
  }
  result = checkWinner(board);
  if (moveCuont === 9) {
    gameOver(result);
    return false;
  }
}
$(".cells").click(changeTurn);
```

You had a number of syntax issues, missing `;`. Also since your function did not define an event parameter, it would not be passed into the function on callback, so you would not have an `event` variable to reference, it would be `null` or `undefined`.

In regards to `return false`, I would review: [Is it better to return `undefined` or `null` from a javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980559/is-it-better-to-return-undefined-or-null-from-a-javascript-function)

Comment: thank you i did it by using     $(".cells").one('click',changeTurn)
ind its work perfectly .