# Async arrow function expected no return value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an application with Firebase oAuth. I followed all the instructions, but my code is returning an error saying that 'asyn arrow function expected no return value'.

I saw that there are multiple posts with the same title, but have not found an answer.

[image]

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();

const config = {
  apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXX',
  authDomain: 'XXXXXXXXX',
  projectId: 'XXXXXXXXX',
  storageBucket: 'XXXXXXXXX',
  messagingSenderId: 'XXXXXXXXX',
  appId: 'XXXXXXXXX',
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const createUserProfileDocument = async (userAuth, additionalData) => {
  if (!userAuth) return;

  const userRef = firestore.doc(`users/${userAuth.uid}`);

  const snapShot = await userRef.get();

  if (!snapShot.exists) {
    const { displayName, email } = userAuth;
    const createdAt = new Date();
    try {
      await userRef.set({
        displayName,
        email,
        createdAt,
        ...additionalData,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error creating user', error.message);
    }
  }

  return userRef;
};


const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });
export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

export default firebase;
```

Comment: Seems like `if (!userAuth) return;` is causing the problem.

Comment: You probably don't want to share your Firebase config until after you've shipped the app and have proper security rules in place.

Answer (score 47):

Change the first line from `if (!userAuth) return` to `if (!userAuth) return {}`, this should do the trick

**Explanation**
The error you're having says `consistent-return` at the end, which basically means your function should consistently return the same type.

With that in mind, if we take a look at the first line in your function

```
if (!userAuth) return;
```

this line returns a `void`, but the last line in the function is returning some other type

```
return userRef;
```

`userRef` is definitely not of type `void` and this is why you are having this error.

Answer (score 8):

The error message is telling you that an arrow function should always or never return a value. Look [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return)

You have `if (!userAuth) return;` and `return userRef;`

Change `if (!userAuth) return {};` should fix the problem.

Answer (score 6):

This rule requires `return` statements to either always or never specify values.

Examples of INCORRECT code for this rule:

```js
function doSomething(condition) {
    if (condition) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

function doSomething(condition) {
    if (condition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Examples of CORRECT code for this rule:

```js
function doSomething(condition) {
    if (condition) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

// or even better:
function doSomething(condition) {
    return condition;
}
```

[Read more](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return)

If you want to disable this rule you can use this comment:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
return userRef;
```

Answer (score 4):

try to replace **return** to **return undefined**

Comment: For most of the cases returning null instead of undefined is better. There is even a eslint rule about that. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980559/is-it-better-to-return-undefined-or-null-from-a-javascript-function

Answer (score 1):

There is a violation of the eslint '[consistent-return](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return)' rule in the code.

This code:

```js
if (!userAuth) return;
```

returns undefined, while the last line of the arrow function:

```js
  return userRef;
};
```

returns `userRef`.

The fix is to return something that isn't undefined in the first case.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```js
if (!userAuth) return;
```

with

```js
if (!userAuth) return undefined;
```